# Golang: declare a single constant

Tags: go, constants, conventions

Which is the preferred way to declare a single constant in Go?

1)

```
const myConst
```

2)

```
const (
        myConst
)
```

Both ways are accepted by `gofmt`. Both ways are found in *stdlib*, though 1) is used more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second form is mainly for grouping several constant declarations.

If you have only one constant, the first form is enough.

for instance [`archive/tar/reader.go`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/archive/tar/reader.go?s=680:861#L25):

```
const maxNanoSecondIntSize = 9
```

But in [`archive/zip/struct.go`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/archive/zip/struct.go):

```
// Compression methods.
const (
        Store   uint16 = 0
        Deflate uint16 = 8
)
```

That doesn't mean you have to group *all* constants in one `const ()`: when you have constants initialized by [iota (successive integer)](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Iota), each block counts.
See for instance [`cmd/yacc/yacc.go`](http://golang.org/src/cmd/yacc/yacc.go)

```
// flags for state generation
const (
    DONE = iota
    MUSTDO
    MUSTLOOKAHEAD
)

// flags for a rule having an action, and being reduced
const (
    ACTFLAG = 1 << (iota + 2)
    REDFLAG
)
```

---

[dalu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2312578/dalu) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838846/golang-declare-a-single-constant/24838866#comment38572918_24838866):

> it can also be done with [`import`](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations), [`type`](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Types), [`var`](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations), and more than once.

It is true, but you will find `iota` only use in a [constant declaration](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_declarations), and that would force you to define multiple `const ()` blocks if you need multiple sets of consecutive integer constants.

Comment: and to extend the answer, it can also be done with import, type, var and more than once.

Comment: @dalu good point. I have included it in the answer for more visibility. I have also added the iota usage as an example of having to use multiple `const ()` blocks.

Comment: In the examples I see constant names in CAPS and CamelCase. What is the preferred way of naming constants?

Comment: @warvariuc the general convention is MixedCaps: http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#mixed-caps. See more at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22688926/6309