# Idiomatic representation of related string constants

Tags: go, naming-conventions, idioms

I am not certain in which way I should represent related string constants, namely language codes, in Go.

1. The [only occurrence](https://golang.org/src/net/http/status.go) in the standard library, of which I am aware, uses untyped string constants and prefixes the variable names with the "type".

   ```
   const LanguageEnglish = "en"
   ```
2. There is the possibility to declare an extra type.

   ```
   type Language string 

   const English Language = "en"
   // or
   const LanguageEnglish Language = "en"
   ```

   But any arbitrary string can be converted to the type anyways, so I can not remark any advantage.

   ```
   Language("en")
   ```

Essentially two questions arose from the prior observations:

1. Should the string constants’ names be prefixed by their "type"?
2. What are the benefits of using a custom type in contrast to untyped
   string constants?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/14426366/13860

Comment: I will correct the terminology, but the question is not a duplicate of the mentioned one (especially regarding naming conventions).

Comment: *"Are there any official conventions, especially regarding the naming?"* The only official documentation on naming conventions, that I know of, can be found [here](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#names). No special mention on naming constants though, so you're free to choose the naming approach that best suits your need.

Comment: *"... so I can not remark any advantage."* You can put methods on your type, you cannot do the same with types you haven't declared yourself, e.g. `string`. For example [this code](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#constants) couldn't implement the stringer interface if it used `float64` directly as the type of the enums.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22688906/13860

Comment: The stdlib uses untyped string consts [all](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#pkg-constants) [over](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#pkg-constants) [the](https://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/#pkg-constants) [place](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants)

Comment: Are you aware of [x/text/language](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/language)? It doesn't answer your actual question, but may obviate it. When dealing with languages, this package would provide the most idiomatic and standard way of using language tags.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! @Flimzy Yes, it isn't. But "LanguageEnglish" is constructed by the same naming scheme as "StatusOK".

Comment: You shouldn't use `Language("en")` if you have a type for your constants. Typically you use `switch`, so you won't get arbitrary string for `Language` type.